# jQuery to populate a 2nd select list

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

There's a [similar question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745704/jquery-populate-items-into-a-select-using-jquery-ajax-json-php), but I wanted to ask it again because ColdFusion is different than PHP.
I have two select lists, the second one is populated from the first.

```
<cfparam name="form.MajorID" default="0">
<cfform name="myForm" preservedata="yes">
<cfselect name="MajorID" query="qryMajor" display="MajorDisplay" value="MajorID" queryPosition="below"
onChange="document.myForm.submit();">
<option value="0">Please Select major topic</option>
</cfselect>
<div>
<cfset qryMinor = objMinor.WhereMajorID(form.MajorID)>
<cfselect name="MinorID" query="qryMinor" display="MinorDisplay" value="MinorID" queryPosition="below" onChange="document.myForm.submit();">
<option value="0">Please Select minor topic</option>
</cfselect>
</div>
</cfform>
```

The pseudocode for Minor.cfc is:

```
SELECT * FROM tblMinor WHERE MajorID=#arguments.MajorID#
```

I'd like to remove the onChange event where it submits the form, and instead have jQuery populate the second select list via Ajax.  I know that there's a Spry example of this, but I'm already using jQuery and would prefer to use it instead of add a second framework into the project.

I know I'll have to change the WhereMajorID function inside of Minor.cfc to access="remote", but I'm pretty bad with the whole looping inside of javaScript thing.

```
$('#MajorID').change(function() {
   // $.post magic happens here
});
```

I hope I've made myself clear with this question.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not really good at this, but let's give it a shot. Minor.cfc is serverside, right? What kind of output does it give?

Comment: If you want to use JSON, this post might help you on your way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2031865/how-do-i-return-json-data-using-jquery-post-to-a-coldfusion-8-cfc

Comment: Minor.cfc can give any kind of output you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are on ColdFusion 8 or higher you can use the data binding feature of cfselect.  Ben Forta has a great post [about it here](http://www.forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2007/5/31/ColdFusion-Ajax-Tutorial-2-Related-Selects)

Here is a little code sample:

```
<cfform>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Media Type:</td>
        <td><cfselect name="mediaid"
                bind="cfc:art.getMedia()"
                bindonload="true" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select Art:</td>
        <td><cfselect name="artid"
                bind="cfc:art.getArt({mediaid})" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</cfform>
```

Comment: Sam Farmer, the king of the one-liners!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Coldfusion, but I do know jQuery:

```
// Bind logic to the change event of the first SELECT
$("#firstSelect").change(function(){
  // Get currently-selected value
  var option = $(this).val();
  // Pass value to a server-side script through id of 'majorID'
  $.post("somepage.php", { 'majorID':option }, function(data) {
    // Remove all options from second SELECT
    $("#secondSelect option").remove();
    // Cycle through returned 'data' variable: i = index, o = object
    $(data).each(function(i,o){
      // Add new option to second SELECT
      $("#secondSelect").append( $("<option>").val(i).text(this) );
    });
  // This indicates the type of data we expect back
  }, "json");
});
```