# How to create a .cfc file using Ajax?

Tags: ajax, jquery, coldfusion, coldfusion-7

I'm trying to create a ColdFusion component(.cfc) file and use Ajax to pass my query.  Am I doing this correctly and can I use Ajax in ColdFusion 7?

**Added from edit comment of OP**

> I have updated this once again and just as I stated above my button click works and my component works but, the call to the component does nothing. Can someone take a look at it one more time to see what the problem could be. I feel like I'm so close. Also, how do I retrieve the returned value?

**Added from edit comment of OP**

> I updated the code but, I'm still not getting anything. Can someone please, please help me understand what I'm missing?

The following is in form.cfm:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function validateFunding(){
        $('#Finalize').click(function(){  
        $.ajax({
             type:"get",
                url: "awardTotals.cfc?method=searchAward",
                data: {total: $("totals").val(), codeNum: $("CodeNum").val(), testYear: $("TestYear").val, selType: $("selType").val, selJuris: $("selJuris").val},
            success: function(data) {
            if (isTotals == true) { alert('There is a match');} else { alert('This does not match);}
            }
        });
          });
    }
```

This is my awardTotal.cfc.

```
    <cfcomponent>
        <cffunction name="searchAward" access="remote" returntype="any">
            <cfargument name="Total" type="numeric" required="true">
            <cfargument name="CodeNum" type="string" required="true">
                    <cfargument name="TestYear" type="numeric" required="true">
                    <cfargument name="SelType" type="numeric" required="true">
                    <cfargument name="SelJuris" type="numeric" required="true">
                <cfset var searchAwards = "">
            <cfquery name="searchAwards" datasource="Test">
             SELECT g.Code1 + g.Code2 + g.Code3 + g.Code4 AS GrandTotal
                     FROM Codes g 
                    WHERE g.CodeNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"  value="#arguments.CodeNum#">
                     AND g.TestYear = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.TestYear#">
                     AND g.SelType = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.SelType#">  
                       AND g.Jurisdiction = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#arguments.SelJuris#">   
             </cfquery> 
           <cfscript>
          if(arguments.Totals = searchAwards.GrandTotal){
             return true;
          } else {
             return false;
          }
        </cfscript>
        </cffunction>
    </cfcomponent>
```

Comment: What's the problem here? If you want to see if you're doing it correctly, run it, if it works, you are.

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, please post it.  If not, then I assume you are not getting the expected results.  So please post your expected results and your actual results.

Comment: "_I updated the code but, I'm still not getting anything._" You are being too vague.  Give us details please.  Are you getting an error?  Is your cfc being called?

Comment: I'm not getting anything.  I don't think my cfc is being called at all.  When I click the button I get nothing.  Nothing at all.

Comment: Is your cfc being called? Check your web/cf server logs.  Your new example appears to be calling a method named `searchAward` but your cfc's function name is `myFunction`.  The function's `access` is set to "public", should be "remote".  Your ajax `data` element seems to reference javascript variables but we cannot see how those are being set (totals, CodeNum, etc).  The ajax `url` element is set to "awardTotals.cfc" (with an s) but your comment says "This is my awardTotal.cfc" (without an s).

Comment: Ok I believe I have made all the necessary changes. I tested the component and received one error and fixed it so now when I test the component it takes me to a coldfusion8 sign in screen.  But, I still don't get anything when I call it from my form.

Comment: What do you mean it takes you "_to a coldfusion8 sign in screen_"? (I thought you were running ColdFusion 7?) You need to get your cfc working from a browser before you even attempt to get it working via ajax. If you have to authenticate to your cfc in a browser your ajax call will need to authenticate as well.  Get it working in a browser first, then try to get ajax working.

Comment: *now when I test the component it takes me to a ...sign in screen* (Edit) That just means the cfc compiles. It may still contain runtime errors - and likely does since the query is still using `form` values and you are using `GET`. You need to test it from a browser as @Miguel-F suggested: `http://yourserver/path/to/awardTotals.cfc?method=searchAward&FundingTotals=some‌​ValueHere&otherParams=.....` After that, you should check out a few jquery tutorials. Learn how to invoke and debug an ajax request. Then you will have a better understanding of how to combine the two.

Comment: @tnbumbray when you edit/update your question on StackOverflow those comments are not visible here. They can only be seen in the edit history.  I have edited your question to include your new comments for others to see.

Comment: If your cfc is working from a browser then you need to copy the URL that you used in the browser and paste it into the URL line of your ajax call: `url: "paste-url-here"`. You are not specifying a server name for your cfc so I suppose it is attempting to call it using localhost. You should really check out some jQuery tutorials to better understand this as @Leigh mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in grandTotal and your method is looking for awardTotals.  you are returning an empty string and looking for a boolean.  Try this :

```
function ValidateFunding(awardTotals){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'awardTotals.cfc',
        data: {method: 'searchAward',  awardTotals: numberToPass},
        success: function(data) {
        if (isTotals == true) { alert('There is a match');} else { alert('This does not match);}
        }
    });
}
```

Then

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cffunction name="myFunction" access="public" returntype="Query">
        <cfargument name="awardTotals" type="string" required="true">

        <cfset var searchAward = queryNew()>
        <cfquery name="searchAward" datasource="Test">
                SELECT g.Code1 + g.Code2 + g.Code3 + g.Code4 AS GrandTotal
                FROM Codes g 
                WHERE g.CodeNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"  value="#form.CodeNum#">
                  AND g.TestYear = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.TestYear#">
                  AND g.SelType = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.SelType#">   
                  AND g.Jurisdiction = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.SelJuris#">    
         </cfquery> 
       <cfscript>
          if(arguments.awardTotals eq searchAward.grandTotal){
             return true;
          } else {
             return false;
          }
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And @billy Cravens is correct. You can't use cfajaxproxy but jquery ajax will work.

Comment: Lance - There are a few typos in the `if` block. It should be `arguments.awardTotals EQ searchAward.grandTotal` (for MX7 compatibility). @tnbumbray - 1) The `FORM` values should be passed in as arguments, rather than referenced directly 2) Do not forget to `var` scope the query name.

Comment: I changed the form and tried to do what was recommended but, nothing happened.  I didn't get an error.  I didn't get anything.  Am I missing something?  I'm calling the function when i click the "Finalize" button but, nothing happens.

Comment: I'm totally new to jquery.  Do I need to install Jquery or can i call the component without using Jquery?

Comment: @Leigh Thanks for the syntax check, I think I got them fixed.  tnbumbray you do need to load the jquery library you can use the google cdn `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` for loading. There are lots of "getting started with jQuery" articles that you should look at to get a full understanding of how it works. I use the `$.ajax` all the time as I prefer it over the cfajaxproxy. Hopely once you get it going this question will help get it working with CF for you

Answer (score 1):

cfajaxproxy was introduced in ColdFusion 8, so it's unavailable on CF7.

However, you can call the CFC in your jQuery ajax() call by appending the method and the parameters to the URL: `awardTotal.cfc?method=myFunction&awardTotals=#awardTotals#`

You'll of course have to use `access="remote"` and return output that JavaScript can handle (again on CF7 your options are a bit limited, as functions like `serializeJson()` were added in CF8 as well)

(see [Invoke ColdFusion function using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999501/invoke-coldfusion-function-using-ajax))

Comment: OK.  I have tried all I know to do and it's not doing anything at all.  I have edited the code at the top to mimic what I have right now.  Can someone please tell me where I'm going wrong?