# Automatic refresh and show more records

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a automatic refresh to load some records in my page. The page is updating every 20 seconds with jquery/ajax.

index.cfm:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("##comments#timeline_id#").load("comments.cfm?timeline_id=#timeline_id#");
var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  $("##comments#timeline_id#").load('comments.cfm?timeline_id=#timeline_id#&randval='+                    
  Math.random());
  }, 20000);
  });
 </script>
```

It shows 5 comments and I want to create a button with "show all comments", of course when there are more available. Also I want to load the extra comments without a page refresh.

Is that something I need to fix on my index.cfm, or should I do this on the comment.cfm page? Can someone point me in the right direction, because I'm stuck on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I try not to use ColdFusion built-in AJAX functions but I always have made an exception with CFDIV. CFDIV seems like a perfect solution for this problem.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_04.html

Comment: Never use the CF AJAX functions...ever. jQuery's `load()` works just as good...maybe even better than... `cfdiv`

Comment: Ben Forta blog - [When Using ColdFusion (AJAX Functions) No Longer Makes Sense](http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense)

Comment: my question is not about using coldfusion. The question is about me want to dynamically load more records in my div. If I can fix that with query, great! I just need some simple samples how to do this.

Comment: @user2483081 Can you post your query?

Comment: It's real basic. Just a cfquery to select the comment rows. After that a cfoutput to show the available records.

Comment: How are you grabbing x amount of rows? Are you using cfquery, cfoutput, or SELECT TOP() ?

Comment: Yeah that could be an option. I could use the cfoutput maxrows opion as well. I was just wondering how I can control it, because the comment.cfm is dynamic loaded with ajax.

Comment: I was thinking maybe you could dynamically load the entire query as well. Put it in a CFC and have ajax load the data. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/999501/invoke-coldfusion-function-using-ajax