# How to use jquery post with multiple methods in target url?

Tags: jquery, ajax, coldfusion

With jquery post() method, posting to Coldfusion component(s) .cfc, does each Coldfusion method/function need to be in a separate component file, or can I have multiple methods/functions per .cfc?

I've seen code for $.ajax() as follows:

```
 $.ajax("url1",
 "post",
 {method:"func1",item:"foo"},
 function(return){
     alert(return)
 })

 $.ajax("url1",
 "post",
 {method:"func2",item:"bar"},
 function(return){
     alert(return)
 })
```

Where the cfc has two cffunctions (func1, and func2).

When I try below (or variants), with either ajax() or post(), it's not working . . . I get 500 errors. (Note: When I place only one of the cffunctions in the cfcomponent, and remove the "method: 'func'" from the "data" parameter object, the calls work).

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("ready!");
    $.post(
        "CFPosts.cfc",
        {method:"getPID",rn:"21703"},
        function(result){
            alert(result);
        });

    $.post(
        "CFPosts.cfc",
        {method:"getTime"},
        function(result){
            alert(result);
        });
})
```

Coldfusion:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cfheader name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*">

    <cfoutput>
        <cffunction name="getPID" access="public" returntype="string">
            <cfargument name="rn" type="string" required="yes">
            <cfquery name="queryPID" datasource="D7SQL">
                SELECT
                    PATHWAYID
                FROM
                    FYP.dbo.STUDENT S
                WHERE
                STUDENTDCID = #rn#
            </cfquery>  
            <cfloop query="queryPID">
                <cfreturn "#PATHWAYID#">
            </cfloop>
        </cffunction>

        <cffunction name="getTime" access="public" returntype="string">
            <cfreturn "#Now()#">
        </cffunction>

    </cfoutput>

</cfcomponent>
```

Any ideas how to have two or more cffunctions per cfc for a post() call? Tks!

Comment: Voting to close as this question has been asked and answered before - http://stackoverflow.com/q/999501/1636917.  And you do not need the `<cfoutput>` tags in your cfcomponent. Remove them.

Comment: In addition, the cfloop serves no purpose. To return the first value from the query, just use `<cfreturn queryPID.PathWayID>`,  no quotes or pound signs needed. Also, always use cfqueryparam to prevent sql injection and localize all function local variables: including query names.

Comment: Many thanks to Miguel and Leigh. Much appreciated!