# ColdFusion CFC loaded through AJAX returns empty response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion, cfc

I'm having trouble calling a CFC through a jQuery ajax call. I've read at least a dozen articles/Overflows on the topic but cannot get a basic "Hello World" to return to the page. My environment is running ColdFusion 11 on Window 2008 R2 and IIS7.5

Here is my CFC:

```
<cfcomponent displayname="BU_ldaptest" extends="ADF.apps.BU_Utils.components.App" hint="BU_ldaptest.">
<cfproperty name="version" value="1_0_0">
    <cffunction name="helloWorld" access="remote" returntype="string" output="false">
        <cfreturn "Hello World!">
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

And here is my CFM:

```
<cfoutput>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
#application.BU_Utils.BU_ldaptest.helloWorld()#
<button onClick="loadCFC();">Load</button>
<script>
    function loadCFC() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/ADF/apps/BU_Utils/components/BU_ldaptest.cfc?method=helloWorld",
            cache: false,
            success: function(msg) {
                $("##result").html(msg);
                console.log(msg);
            },
            error: function(msg) {
                $("##result").html("Failed");
            }
        });
        console.log("function execute");
    };
</script>
<div id="result">...</div>
</cfoutput>
```

In the CFM, that "#application.BU_Utils...#" variable does correctly print "Hello World!" in the browser.

I do not have any Web Services setup in the CF Admin interface, are they required for something like this to work? I also know that I'll eventually want my cfc to return JSON, which it will once I can just get this simple string to print out. I've gone through this Overflow over and over... [Invoke ColdFusion function using AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999501/invoke-coldfusion-function-using-ajax)

Thank you.

Comment: to make debugging easier, skip the ajax and just type into your browser url: `http://yourdomain.com/ADF/apps/BU_Utils/components/BU_ldaptest.cfc?method=helloWorld` and see what it returns.  If it's still blank, try just .cfc and see if it tries to redirect to doc explorer, or any other http error.  If there are http err, double check if your webserver is set up right.

Comment: Thank Henry, it just returns a blank page (nothing in the source), whether with or without the method. No doc explorer either.

Comment: then you should double check your webserver config.  Run webserver configuration tool.

Comment: Anything specific that I'm looking for that might be misconfigured? This is on my production box and everything else works normally, but this is the first time I've tried to do ajax calls to a cfc.

Comment: I get the same thing... this is bugging me, so I'll figure it out for ya.

Comment: Removed (had to remove it from the App.cfc as well) and it still isn't returning anything. Crazyness.

Is it normal not to have any Web Services setup?

Comment: I ended up getting your code working as is, but removing the extends attribute. My issue was I had to redo the connector to my test site for whatever reason. Try removing the extends attribute.

Comment: Also for kicks... try a different browser in case something's odd with an extension or cache.

Comment: One last thing... back in CF9 there was an issue where if onRequest() was in your app.cfc it did the same thing. See if you have onRequest() and comment it out if you do for kicks.

Comment: One last last thing... Be sure you have updates installed... preferably update 6.

Comment: Okay, that seems to have done it! Sorta. I moved it out of our CMS application development framework area and into a folder off the site root and it seems that it actually loaded! Man, if that's the only reason I lost a whole day fighting through this... 

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

in my application i have to display a table using ajax, so i wraped my table in cfsavecontentand returned the cfsavecontent variable.

Example:

```
    <!--- declaring variable to return to ajax --->
    <cfset VAR PlayList =''>


    <!--- Saving content inside cfsavecontent to playlist variable --->
    <cfsavecontent variable="PlayList">

        <table border="1" class="companytab1">
        <thead>
            <tr class="header">
                <th>SlNo</th>
                ....
                <th>Company Name</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <!--- SlNo--->
                <td align="center" >1</td>
                ....
                <!--- Company Name--->
                <td align="center" >Asdf</td>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </cfsavecontent>

<cfreturn PlayList>
```